# Make one of the Parameters an "Optional Parameter" in model - - ModelBuilder (ArcGIS Pro v2.5.0)

Tags: modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, parameters

It is possible that there are several workarounds in ArcPy or scripts but I need this to work in Modelbuilder.

Simply I want the model to run with the populated and un-populated parameter fields (i.e. the Optional field is blank).

In my model I have the following parameters:
1. Street Address (point)(Required)
2. Property Boundary (polygon)(Required)
3. Buildings (polygon)(OPTIONAL).

[image]

The first step is to "Spatial Join" the Address to Properties (to apply the Address to the properties in my study area). Following this, I want to apply the address_property's address to the buildings that are within the property. However, sometimes I won't have the buildings feature and would like to continue with just the address_properties. Needless to say, this will form part of a larger tool.

The workaround to make this parameter Optional is to disconnect the input line and in the model's Properties -> parameters change it by the drop-down list. The thing is once all this is done and I try to run the model by right-clicking on the model and click on Open - the tool still asked me to populate the parameter.

[image]

This should be straight-forward but I possibly jinked it by saying that.

Comment: I'd make this an answer, but I dont really understand (perhaps because what you want to do isn't possible in Modelbuilder) -- can you make use of the LOGICALs, such as "If Data Exists"?

Comment: I tried going down the If Data Exists route but no love - the tool in the end still ask me to populate the input parameter "Building" and won't run the tool otherwise.